# Date picker dialog button text change

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I am using several languages in the app, so I need to switch the texts on the date picker buttons.
I'm writing a simple code that looks like this:

```
 val datePickerDialog = builder.build()
    datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, R.string.common_dialog_cancel)
    datePickerDialog
```

I'm returning the dialog on the last line. The problem is that the second line identifies the errors I cannot resolve. "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."
As far as I know, alertDialog should have a method setButton() that takes a button and a string as arguments, but something is not right in my code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs there is no function that supports these 2 arguments. I guess you should use this one:

```
public void setButton (int whichButton, 
            CharSequence text, 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

[Link to docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog#setButton(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

So you have to add a 3rd argument with the click listener.